# Prove that $\det(I+ Dzz')= 1+z'Dz.$

Tags: analysis, solution-verification, determinant

I am working on a proof and I am struggling with the last step. Which property of a determinant could be used here? I've searched the matrix cookbook but is was to no avail.
$D$ is a $q \times q$ matrix, and $z$ is a $q \times 1$ vector.

$$\det(I+ Dzz')=
1+z'Dz.$$

Comment: Yes, | | means determinant and the accent a transpose

Comment: Is $\times$ the usual matrix product? (And can we just ignore the $2ik$ or has it got a relevant meaning?)

Comment: yes that is indeed the usual matrix product and the subscript can be ignored

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just an application of the formula for the eigenvalues of matrices of rank $1$. A matrix in the form $A=wv^\top$ has an explicit Jordan form in terms of $w$ and $v$. Specifically:

- if $v^\top w\ne 0$, then $wv^\top$ is diagonalizable with $\ker (A-(v^\top w)I)=\operatorname{span}{w}$ and $\ker A=\ker(v^\top)$.
- if $v^\top w=0$, $v\ne0$ and $w\ne 0$, then the matrix is nilpotent, specifically $\ker A=\ker v^\top$ and $\ker A^2=\Bbb R^n$.
- if $v=0$ or $w=0$, then $A=0$.

Either way, it follows that the (generalized) eigenvalues of $A$ are $(\underbrace{0,\cdots, 0}_{(n-1)\text{ times}},v^\top w)$. Therefore $\det (I+A)=1+v^\top w$.

In your case, $w=Dz$ and $v=z$.